# Visual composer WordPress plugin tabs not working

Tags: wordpress, tabs, content-management-system, visual-composer

After I updated my WordPress, the content of the visual composer plugins in tabs are not displaying properly. They are showing up as a sequential list. Can anyone direct me on how to go about fixing it?

The tabs in the backend editor look ok:

[image]

The actual page shows them as a list:

[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

may be you forgot to add body class, for reference check this `<body <?php body_class(); ?>`>`

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where I can check that?

Comment: just view page source and check whether js_composer class in <body> tag or not ?

Comment: Did you find any solution from my given answer @locke14

Comment: so now add this code into themes header.php in body tag like this `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Thanks Aslam, it was really helpful.. :D